# Hide button after form submit and save state to localstorage

Tags: plugins, jquery, forms, plugin-contact-form-7

I'm trying to disable a form button (contact form 7) after submitting and then save the disabled state to localstorage. This disables the button after submitting:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#buttonID").click(function () {
    setTimeout(function () { disableButton(); }, 100);
});

function disableButton() {
    $("#buttonID").prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

How can I save the disabled state to localstorage so it stays disable?

Answer (score 0):

You can save an item to local storage with one line.  Something like this...

`localStorage.setItem("isDisabled", "true");`

Then you can check for the value later by doing something like this...

```
if(localStorage.getItem("isDisabled")===null) {
   //
}
```

Or update the value from true to false ...

`localStorage.setItem('isDisabled', 'false');`

Answer (score 0):

To save a key (`buttonID.disabled` in this example) to localstorage you can use:

```js
localStorage.setItem('buttonID.disabled', 1)
```

To read that key later:

```
localStorage.getItem('buttonID.disabled')
```

Implementing that in your code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#buttonID").click(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
      disableButton();
      // persist key
      localStorage.setItem('buttonID.disabled', 1)
    }, 100);

    // disable button later based on localstorage key presence
    localStorage.getItem('buttonID.disabled') && disableButton()
});

function disableButton() {
    $("#buttonID").prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I implemented this version, but when I reload the page (Chrome) the button does not have the disabled state saved unfortunately

Comment: np. Does `$("#buttonID").prop('disabled', true)` disable the button if you run it in the devtools console? if so, does `localStorage.getItem('buttonID.disabled')` return anything?

Comment: np. Does `$("#buttonID").prop('disabled', true)` disable the button if you run it in the devtools console? if so, does `localStorage.getItem('buttonID.disabled')` return anything?

Comment: Yes, before submitting:
`<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit" id="buttonID">` and after submitting `<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit" id="buttonID" **disabled**>` - if I check localstorage with `if("buttonID.disabled" in localStorage){ alert('yes'); } else { alert('no'); }` I'll get a yes, but the disabled state is still gone :/

Comment: In your example instead of `alert('yes')` call `disableButton()`. If the element is not rendered yet then you'll have to wait, using timeout or mutation observers. Calling `$("#buttonID").length` will tell you if the button is rendered at the time of the script call.

Comment: Can you maybe elaborate the last comment, I've never used the .length property :/